# This is an EIGRP Topology with frame relay. I'm not able to figure out why R1's topology table doesn't a show feasible successor for 192.168.2.0/24

Tags: cisco, routing, router, packet-tracer, eigrp

```
P 192.168.1.0/24, 1 successors, FD is 2730496
        via 172.16.124.2 (2730496/2218496), Serial3/0
        via 172.16.124.3 (3193856/2681856), Serial3/0
P 192.168.2.0/24, 1 successors, FD is 2681856
        via 172.16.124.3 (2681856/2169856), Serial3/0
P 192.168.3.0/24, 1 successors, FD is 2730496
        via 172.16.124.4 (2730496/2218496), Serial3/0
        via 172.16.124.3 (3193856/2681856), Serial3/0
```

**[Previous question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/23662/why-r1s-topology-table-doesnt-show-feasible-successor-for-192-168-2-0-24) was not answered properly, that's why I'm posting it again by making some corrections.**

Topology looks like this:
[image]

1) R1's Neighbor table, Topology Table and Routing table looks like this:

```
R1#show ip eigrp neighbors
IP-EIGRP neighbors for process 1
H   Address                 Interface       Hold Uptime   SRTT   RTO  Q  Seq
                                            (sec)         (ms)       Cnt Num
2   172.16.124.2            Se3/0            128 00:04:29 1179  5000  0  18
1   172.16.124.3            Se3/0            132 00:04:29  984  5000  0  17
0   172.16.124.4            Se3/0            136 00:04:29  982  5000  0  15

R1#show ip eigrp topology
IP-EIGRP Topology Table for AS(1)/ID(10.1.3.1)

Codes: P - Passive, A - Active, U - Update, Q - Query, R - Reply,
       r - reply Status, s - sia Status

P 10.2.0.0/22, 1 successors, FD is 2297856
        via 172.16.124.2 (2297856/128256), Serial3/0
P 10.3.1.0/24, 2 successors, FD is 3370496
        via 172.16.124.2 (3370496/2858496), Serial3/0
        via 172.16.124.4 (3370496/2858496), Serial3/0
P 10.1.3.0/24, 1 successors, FD is 128256
        via Connected, Loopback3
P 10.3.0.0/22, 1 successors, FD is 2297856
        via 172.16.124.3 (2297856/128256), Serial3/0
P 10.2.1.0/24, 1 successors, FD is 3321856
        via 172.16.124.3 (3321856/2809856), Serial3/0
        via 172.16.124.4 (3370496/2858496), Serial3/0
P 10.1.2.0/24, 1 successors, FD is 128256
        via Connected, Loopback2
P 10.2.2.0/24, 1 successors, FD is 3321856
        via 172.16.124.3 (3321856/2809856), Serial3/0
        via 172.16.124.4 (3370496/2858496), Serial3/0
P 10.3.3.0/24, 2 successors, FD is 3370496
        via 172.16.124.2 (3370496/2858496), Serial3/0
        via 172.16.124.4 (3370496/2858496), Serial3/0
P 10.1.1.0/24, 1 successors, FD is 128256
        via Connected, Loopback1
P 10.2.3.0/24, 1 successors, FD is 3321856
        via 172.16.124.3 (3321856/2809856), Serial3/0
        via 172.16.124.4 (3370496/2858496), Serial3/0
P 10.3.2.0/24, 2 successors, FD is 3370496
        via 172.16.124.2 (3370496/2858496), Serial3/0
        via 172.16.124.4 (3370496/2858496), Serial3/0
P 192.168.1.0/24, 1 successors, FD is 2730496
        via 172.16.124.2 (2730496/2218496), Serial3/0
        via 172.16.124.3 (3193856/2681856), Serial3/0
P 192.168.2.0/24, 1 successors, FD is 2681856
        via 172.16.124.3 (2681856/2169856), Serial3/0
P 192.168.3.0/24, 1 successors, FD is 2730496
        via 172.16.124.4 (2730496/2218496), Serial3/0
        via 172.16.124.3 (3193856/2681856), Serial3/0
P 172.16.124.0/29, 1 successors, FD is 2169856
        via Connected, Serial3/0

R1#show ip route
Codes: C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route

Gateway of last resort is not set

     172.16.0.0/29 is subnetted, 1 subnets
C       172.16.124.0 is directly connected, Serial3/0
     10.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 11 subnets, 2 masks
D       10.3.1.0/24 [90/3370496] via 172.16.124.4, 00:04:39, Serial3/0
                    [90/3370496] via 172.16.124.2, 00:04:39, Serial3/0
D       10.2.0.0/22 [90/2297856] via 172.16.124.2, 00:04:39, Serial3/0
C       10.1.3.0/24 is directly connected, Loopback3
D       10.3.0.0/22 [90/2297856] via 172.16.124.3, 00:04:40, Serial3/0
D       10.2.1.0/24 [90/3321856] via 172.16.124.3, 00:04:40, Serial3/0
C       10.1.2.0/24 is directly connected, Loopback2
D       10.3.3.0/24 [90/3370496] via 172.16.124.4, 00:04:40, Serial3/0
                    [90/3370496] via 172.16.124.2, 00:04:40, Serial3/0
D       10.2.2.0/24 [90/3321856] via 172.16.124.3, 00:04:40, Serial3/0
C       10.1.1.0/24 is directly connected, Loopback1
D       10.3.2.0/24 [90/3370496] via 172.16.124.4, 00:04:41, Serial3/0
                    [90/3370496] via 172.16.124.2, 00:04:41, Serial3/0
D       10.2.3.0/24 [90/3321856] via 172.16.124.3, 00:04:41, Serial3/0
D    192.168.1.0/24 [90/2730496] via 172.16.124.2, 00:04:41, Serial3/0
D    192.168.2.0/24 [90/2681856] via 172.16.124.3, 00:04:41, Serial3/0
D    192.168.3.0/24 [90/2730496] via 172.16.124.4, 00:04:41, Serial3/0
```

2) R1 running configs:

```
R1's running configs:

R1#show running-config
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 2166 bytes
!
upgrade fpd auto
version 12.4
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R1
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
enable secret 5 $1$tImO$nXOKvyq7gRSwqCiLPJQJO.
!
no aaa new-model
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
ip cef
!
!
!
!
no ip domain lookup
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
key chain EIGRP_KEYS
 key 1
   key-string cisco1
   accept-lifetime 00:00:00 Jan 1 2015 00:00:00 Feb 1 2015
   send-lifetime 00:00:00 Jan 1 2015 00:00:00 Feb 1 2015
 key 2
   key-string cisco2
   accept-lifetime 00:00:00 Jan 28 2015 infinite
   send-lifetime 00:00:00 Jan 28 2015 infinite
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
archive
 log config
  hidekeys
!
!
!
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
ip ssh version 1
!
!
!
!
interface Loopback1
 ip address 10.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Loopback2
 ip address 10.1.2.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Loopback3
 ip address 10.1.3.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 172.30.8.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex half
!
interface FastEthernet1/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 duplex half
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 negotiation auto
!
interface Serial3/0
 ip address 172.16.124.1 255.255.255.248
 encapsulation frame-relay
 no ip split-horizon eigrp 1
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/3
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
router eigrp 1
 network 10.0.0.0
 network 172.16.0.0
 network 172.30.0.0
 no auto-summary
!
ip forward-protocol nd
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
!
!
logging alarm informational
no cdp log mismatch duplex
!
!
!
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
gatekeeper
 shutdown
!
banner motd ^C
*****************************
This is a CISCO ROUTER
*****************************^C
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 password cisco
 logging synchronous
 login
 stopbits 1
line aux 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 password cisco
 login
line vty 5 15
 password cisco
 login
!
!
end
```

3) R2 running configs and routing table:

```
R2#show running-config
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 2121 bytes
!
upgrade fpd auto
version 12.4
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R2
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
enable secret 5 $1$UbxQ$Vsto.IK7WKlg8MkuYywEs1
!
no aaa new-model
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
ip cef
!
!
!
!
no ip domain lookup
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
key chain EIGRP_KEYS
 key 1
   key-string cisco1
   accept-lifetime 00:00:00 Jan 1 2015 00:00:00 Feb 1 2015
   send-lifetime 00:00:00 Jan 1 2015 00:00:00 Feb 1 2015
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
archive
 log config
  hidekeys
!
!
!
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
ip ssh version 1
!
!
!
!
interface Loopback1
 ip address 10.2.1.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Loopback2
 ip address 10.2.2.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Loopback3
 ip address 10.2.3.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 duplex half
!
interface FastEthernet1/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 duplex half
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 negotiation auto
!
interface Serial3/0
 ip address 172.16.124.2 255.255.255.248
 encapsulation frame-relay
 ip summary-address eigrp 1 10.2.0.0 255.255.252.0 5
 serial restart-delay 0
 frame-relay map ip 172.16.124.3 201
!
interface Serial3/1
 bandwidth 1500
 ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/3
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
router eigrp 1
 network 10.0.0.0
 network 172.16.0.0
 network 192.168.1.0
 no auto-summary
!
ip forward-protocol nd
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
!
!
logging alarm informational
no cdp log mismatch duplex
!
!
!
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
gatekeeper
 shutdown
!
banner motd ^C
*****************************
This is a CISCO ROUTER
*****************************^C
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 password cisco
 logging synchronous
 login
 stopbits 1
line aux 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 password cisco
 login
line vty 5 15
 password cisco
 login
!
!
end

R2#show ip route
Codes: C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route

Gateway of last resort is not set

     172.16.0.0/29 is subnetted, 1 subnets
C       172.16.124.0 is directly connected, Serial3/0
     10.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 11 subnets, 2 masks
D       10.3.1.0/24 [90/2858496] via 192.168.1.2, 00:17:06, Serial3/1
D       10.2.0.0/22 is a summary, 00:17:05, Null0
D       10.1.3.0/24 [90/2297856] via 172.16.124.1, 00:17:06, Serial3/0
D       10.3.0.0/22 [90/2809856] via 172.16.124.1, 00:17:05, Serial3/0
C       10.2.1.0/24 is directly connected, Loopback1
D       10.1.2.0/24 [90/2297856] via 172.16.124.1, 00:17:06, Serial3/0
D       10.3.3.0/24 [90/2858496] via 192.168.1.2, 00:17:06, Serial3/1
C       10.2.2.0/24 is directly connected, Loopback2
D       10.1.1.0/24 [90/2297856] via 172.16.124.1, 00:17:06, Serial3/0
D       10.3.2.0/24 [90/2858496] via 192.168.1.2, 00:17:06, Serial3/1
C       10.2.3.0/24 is directly connected, Loopback3
C    192.168.1.0/24 is directly connected, Serial3/1
D    192.168.2.0/24 [90/2730496] via 192.168.1.2, 00:17:07, Serial3/1
D    192.168.3.0/24 [90/2730496] via 192.168.1.2, 00:17:07, Serial3/1
```

4) R3's running configs and routing table:

```
R3#show running-config
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 2273 bytes
!
upgrade fpd auto
version 12.4
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R3
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
enable secret 5 $1$fhTy$oS62/3CBdLhdKH89ogXQE0
!
no aaa new-model
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
ip cef
!
!
!
!
no ip domain lookup
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
key chain EIGRP_KEYS
 key 1
   key-string cisco1
   accept-lifetime 00:00:00 Jan 1 2015 00:00:00 Feb 1 2015
   send-lifetime 00:00:00 Jan 1 2015 00:00:00 Feb 1 2015
 key 2
   key-string cisco2
   accept-lifetime 00:00:00 Jan 28 2015 infinite
   send-lifetime 00:00:00 Jan 28 2015 infinite
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
archive
 log config
  hidekeys
!
!
!
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
ip ssh version 1
!
!
!
!
interface Loopback1
 ip address 10.3.1.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Loopback2
 ip address 10.3.2.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Loopback3
 ip address 10.3.3.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 duplex half
!
interface FastEthernet1/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 duplex half
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 negotiation auto
!
interface Serial3/0
 ip address 172.16.124.3 255.255.255.248
 encapsulation frame-relay
 ip summary-address eigrp 1 10.3.0.0 255.255.252.0 5
 serial restart-delay 0
 frame-relay map ip 172.16.124.2 301 broadcast
!
interface Serial3/1
 ip address 192.168.3.1 255.255.255.0
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/2
 ip address 192.168.2.2 255.255.255.0
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/3
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
router eigrp 1
 network 10.0.0.0
 network 172.16.0.0
 network 192.168.2.0
 network 192.168.3.0
 no auto-summary
!
ip forward-protocol nd
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
!
!
logging alarm informational
no cdp log mismatch duplex
!
!
!
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
gatekeeper
 shutdown
!
banner motd ^C
*****************************
This is a CISCO ROUTER
*****************************^C
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 password cisco
 logging synchronous
 login
 stopbits 1
line aux 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 password cisco
 login
line vty 5 15
 password cisco
 login
!
!
end

R3#show ip route
Codes: C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route

Gateway of last resort is not set

     172.16.0.0/29 is subnetted, 1 subnets
C       172.16.124.0 is directly connected, Serial3/0
     10.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 11 subnets, 2 masks
C       10.3.1.0/24 is directly connected, Loopback1
D       10.2.0.0/22 [90/2809856] via 172.16.124.1, 00:18:55, Serial3/0
D       10.1.3.0/24 [90/2297856] via 172.16.124.1, 00:18:56, Serial3/0
D       10.3.0.0/22 is a summary, 00:18:55, Null0
D       10.2.1.0/24 [90/2809856] via 192.168.2.1, 00:18:55, Serial3/2
D       10.1.2.0/24 [90/2297856] via 172.16.124.1, 00:18:56, Serial3/0
C       10.3.3.0/24 is directly connected, Loopback3
D       10.2.2.0/24 [90/2809856] via 192.168.2.1, 00:18:55, Serial3/2
D       10.1.1.0/24 [90/2297856] via 172.16.124.1, 00:18:56, Serial3/0
C       10.3.2.0/24 is directly connected, Loopback2
D       10.2.3.0/24 [90/2809856] via 192.168.2.1, 00:18:56, Serial3/2
D    192.168.1.0/24 [90/2681856] via 192.168.2.1, 00:18:56, Serial3/2
C    192.168.2.0/24 is directly connected, Serial3/2
D    192.168.3.0/24 [90/2681856] via 192.168.2.1, 00:18:56, Serial3/2
```

5) R4's running configs and routing table:

```
R4#show running-config
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1443 bytes
!
upgrade fpd auto
version 12.4
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R4
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
no aaa new-model
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
ip cef
!
!
!
!
no ip domain lookup
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
archive
 log config
  hidekeys
!
!
!
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
ip ssh version 1
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 duplex half
!
interface FastEthernet1/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 duplex half
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 negotiation auto
!
interface Serial3/0
 ip address 192.168.3.2 255.255.255.0
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/1
 ip address 192.168.1.2 255.255.255.0
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/2
 ip address 192.168.2.1 255.255.255.0
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/3
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
router eigrp 1
 network 192.168.1.0
 network 192.168.2.0
 network 192.168.3.0
 no auto-summary
!
ip forward-protocol nd
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
!
!
logging alarm informational
no cdp log mismatch duplex
!
!
!
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
gatekeeper
 shutdown
!
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
 stopbits 1
line aux 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
end

R4#show ip route
Codes: C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route

Gateway of last resort is not set

     172.16.0.0/29 is subnetted, 1 subnets
D       172.16.124.0 [90/2681856] via 192.168.3.1, 00:21:09, Serial3/0
                     [90/2681856] via 192.168.2.2, 00:21:09, Serial3/2
                     [90/2681856] via 192.168.1.1, 00:21:09, Serial3/1
     10.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 11 subnets, 2 masks
D       10.3.1.0/24 [90/2297856] via 192.168.2.2, 00:22:10, Serial3/2
D       10.2.0.0/22 [90/3321856] via 192.168.3.1, 00:20:14, Serial3/0
                    [90/3321856] via 192.168.2.2, 00:20:14, Serial3/2
D       10.1.3.0/24 [90/2809856] via 192.168.3.1, 00:20:15, Serial3/0
                    [90/2809856] via 192.168.2.2, 00:20:15, Serial3/2
                    [90/2809856] via 192.168.1.1, 00:20:15, Serial3/1
D       10.3.0.0/22 [90/3321856] via 192.168.3.1, 00:20:14, Serial3/0
                    [90/3321856] via 192.168.1.1, 00:20:14, Serial3/1
D       10.2.1.0/24 [90/2297856] via 192.168.1.1, 00:22:06, Serial3/1
D       10.1.2.0/24 [90/2809856] via 192.168.3.1, 00:20:16, Serial3/0
                    [90/2809856] via 192.168.2.2, 00:20:16, Serial3/2
                    [90/2809856] via 192.168.1.1, 00:20:16, Serial3/1
D       10.3.3.0/24 [90/2297856] via 192.168.2.2, 00:22:10, Serial3/2
D       10.2.2.0/24 [90/2297856] via 192.168.1.1, 00:22:06, Serial3/1
D       10.1.1.0/24 [90/2809856] via 192.168.3.1, 00:20:16, Serial3/0
                    [90/2809856] via 192.168.2.2, 00:20:16, Serial3/2
                    [90/2809856] via 192.168.1.1, 00:20:16, Serial3/1
D       10.3.2.0/24 [90/2297856] via 192.168.2.2, 00:22:10, Serial3/2
D       10.2.3.0/24 [90/2297856] via 192.168.1.1, 00:22:06, Serial3/1
C    192.168.1.0/24 is directly connected, Serial3/1
C    192.168.2.0/24 is directly connected, Serial3/2
C    192.168.3.0/24 is directly connected, Serial3/0
```

6) R5's running configs and routing table:

```
R5#show running-config
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1675 bytes
!
upgrade fpd auto
version 12.4
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R5
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
enable secret 5 $1$bO2q$Yzyc3mFfHaiVGiOOlz27l0
!
no aaa new-model
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
ip cef
!
!
!
!
no ip domain lookup
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
archive
 log config
  hidekeys
!
!
!
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
ip ssh version 1
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 duplex half
!
interface FastEthernet1/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 duplex half
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 negotiation auto
!
interface Serial3/0
 bandwidth 1500
 ip address 192.168.3.1 255.255.255.0
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/3
 ip address 172.16.124.4 255.255.255.248
 encapsulation frame-relay
 serial restart-delay 0
!
router eigrp 1
 network 172.16.0.0
 network 192.168.3.0
 no auto-summary
!
ip forward-protocol nd
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
!
!
logging alarm informational
no cdp log mismatch duplex
!
!
!
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
gatekeeper
 shutdown
!
banner motd ^C
*****************************
This is a CISCO ROUTER
*****************************^C
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 password cisco
 logging synchronous
 login
 stopbits 1
line aux 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 password cisco
 login
line vty 5 15
 password cisco
 login
!
!
end

R5#show ip rou
R5#show ip route
Codes: C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route

Gateway of last resort is not set

     172.16.0.0/29 is subnetted, 1 subnets
C       172.16.124.0 is directly connected, Serial3/3
     10.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 11 subnets, 2 masks
D       10.3.1.0/24 [90/2858496] via 192.168.3.2, 00:21:30, Serial3/0
D       10.2.0.0/22 [90/2809856] via 172.16.124.1, 00:21:29, Serial3/3
D       10.1.3.0/24 [90/2297856] via 172.16.124.1, 00:21:30, Serial3/3
D       10.3.0.0/22 [90/2809856] via 172.16.124.1, 00:21:29, Serial3/3
D       10.2.1.0/24 [90/2858496] via 192.168.3.2, 00:21:29, Serial3/0
D       10.1.2.0/24 [90/2297856] via 172.16.124.1, 00:21:30, Serial3/3
D       10.3.3.0/24 [90/2858496] via 192.168.3.2, 00:21:30, Serial3/0
D       10.2.2.0/24 [90/2858496] via 192.168.3.2, 00:21:29, Serial3/0
D       10.1.1.0/24 [90/2297856] via 172.16.124.1, 00:21:30, Serial3/3
D       10.3.2.0/24 [90/2858496] via 192.168.3.2, 00:21:30, Serial3/0
D       10.2.3.0/24 [90/2858496] via 192.168.3.2, 00:21:30, Serial3/0
D    192.168.1.0/24 [90/2730496] via 192.168.3.2, 00:21:30, Serial3/0
D    192.168.2.0/24 [90/2730496] via 192.168.3.2, 00:21:30, Serial3/0
C    192.168.3.0/24 is directly connected, Serial3/0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm not able to figure out why R1's topology table doesn't show
>   feasible successor for `192.168.2.0/24`?

Remember the feasible successor rule: A feasible successor is a path whose reported distance is less than the feasible distance. If you look at the three routers which could tell R1 about `192.168.2.0/24`, what are the reported distances? Compare those against the feasible distance.

The feasible distance R1 shows in its topology table for `192.168.2.0/24` is `2681856`.

Reported distance for:

- R2 is `2730496`
- R3 is `2169856` as the successor
- R5 is `2730496`

Clearly, no reported distance, other than R3, is less than the feasible distance, so there is no feasible successor.